# Putting javascript code and css styles directly in the jsp page

Tags: spring-mvc

I am developing a spring mvc application using thymeleaf and bootstrap. I have all the javascript and css styles directly embedded into my thymeleaf template. So my question is, apart from readability and code maintainability issues, what are the other type of issues i might face if i mix javascript, css and thymeleaf together? will there be any impact the performance of the page load time?

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about huge Javascript and CSS codes that will be embedded to the page then definitely there are performance concern. It will increase the size of the page so the load time will be bigger compared to externalizing them. Also, if they are externalized, they can be minified in order to minimize the download time, so that the page load will be finished faster.